Difficulty in Flashing OS to SD Card using Node.js Application with Etcher SDK
I'm currently working on a Node.js application aimed at flashing an operating system onto an SD card. For this purpose, I'm utilizing the Etcher SDK. Initially, I encountered issues with detecting external SD cards, but after making some modifications to the source code, I managed to overcome this hurdle. However, I'm now facing difficulties in the actual flashing process.
I've made some changes to the original source code, which you can find in this sandbox link. The application is only runs locally using the command node dist/app.js /path/to/os/my-os.img.
I'm unable to proceed with flashing the OS onto it. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this issue. Additionally, if there are alternative methods or libraries for achieving OS flashing via a Node.js application, I'm open to exploring those options as well.
Thank you in advance for your help!
